# How to propagate info (variable value change) from a makefile child rule to a parent rule (i.e., up the dependency graph)?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to change a Makefile variable in a rule and have the new value be available **globally**. The use case I have is to convey that a child rule was triggered up to its parent rule(s) so that the parent(s) could modify their behavior accordingly.

A target-specific variable will NOT do (e.g., https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific), as that will only propagate the information downstream in the dependency graph (i.e., the variable will have the new value in that target's recipe and all its prerequisites' recipes, but NOT in its parent(s)' recipe(s)).

Currently the hack I am doing is to resort to the file system to record this **global information** and read it in a parent rule:

```
opt = ''
all: b
        @echo global opt = ${opt}
        @echo file opt  = $(shell cat opt)
        echo '' >opt

b: opt = 'b'
b: a
        @echo b-specific opt = ${opt}
        cat a >b
        echo 'b' >opt
a:
        touch a

clean:
        -rm -f a b opt
```

The output of `make clean; make; make` (which is as expected) is:

```
rm -f a b opt
touch a
b-specific opt = b
cat a >b
echo 'b' >opt
global opt =
file opt = b
echo '' >opt
global opt =
file opt =
echo '' >opt
```

The goal is to achieve this without resorting to reading/writing a file as a way of updating and passing information 'upstream' in the dependency graph.
The flavor of Make this is needed for is GNU Make (I have GNU Make 4.3, for completeness), but solutions in bare/standard Make could be insightful too.

Comment: You could try to add `$(eval opt = NEWVALUE)` in the recipe (see [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function)).

Comment: Renaud's suggestion is the only way to do it, from inside make.  There's no way to do it (other than writing files) in any other version of make besides GNU make.

Comment: Thanks, @RenaudPacalet. That usage of `eval` (i.e., the fact that its result is always the empty string so it could be placed anywhere including in a recipe) completely escaped me. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add `$(eval opt = NEWVALUE)` in the recipe (see the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function)). Demo:

```
$ cat Makefile 
.PHONY: foo bar baz

VAR := foo

foo1:
    @echo "in $@ VAR = $(VAR)"

foo2: bar
    @echo "in $@ VAR = $(VAR)"

bar:
    $(eval VAR = bar)

$ make foo1
in foo1 VAR = foo
$ make foo2
in foo2 VAR = bar
```